# Switch Case is getting triggered by itself in C

Tags: c, file, switch-statement, infinite-loop

I have a file student.txt and it has a content like

```
Name RollNo Address ...\n
Name RollNo Address ...\n
```

And I have written a function to search a Name in the file
it's menu driven and goes like

```
 std student;
 FILE *file = NULL;
 int choice;
 char name[20];
 while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter the choice\n1.Insert\t2.Append\t3.Search\t4.Display: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            //insertion
            break;
        case 2:
            // append 
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter the student name to be searched: ");
            scanf("%d", &name);
            search(name, &file);
            break;
        case 4:
            // display
            break;
        default:
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

search function is

```
void search(char ele[], FILE **fileptr)
{
    *fileptr = freopen("student.txt", "r", *fileptr);
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, 100, *fileptr) != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(line, ele) != NULL)
        {
            getchar();
            printf("Congrats !!\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("not found\n");
    fclose(*fileptr);
}
```

But when i run this though has a filename matching filename it goes to an infinite loop and executes display function and triggers search function itself infinitely

Comment: No in the insertion function i used fopen and opened the file in write mode so i closed that and reopened

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking of something else.

Comment: You're not reading your student name correctly in case 3 - you should be using the `%s` conversion specifier, and you should not be using the `&` operator.  You should also check the result of `scanf` - if it's 0, then you didn't successfully read anything and will need to clear out the input stream before trying again.  An easy way to clear the stream is a loop like `while ( getchar() != '\n' );`.

Comment: Yes you are right! The format specifier is wrong , Thank You !!! :)

Comment: I am not sure this warrants an answer because it is covered numerous times on SO.  `scanf("%d", &choice);` reads decimal digits only.  The newline you necessarily also enter remains in the buffer, when ``scanf("%d", &choice);` is next called it terminates immediately because of the newline, but still leaves it in the buffer.

Comment: Yes , i get that because of which there is an infinite loop !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the data is not taken in correctly using a correct format specifier.

In `case 3`, in the `scanf` function, use the format specifier

```
%s
```

instead of

```
%d
```

That will stop the infinite loop.